# Cannot print View title in View template

Tags: views, 8, theming

How can I print the title of my view in views-view.html.twig?

I have tried both `{{ title }}` and `{{ label }}` but neither work.

[image]
[image]

You can see the title is set in the View, and the template is using `{{ title }}`

Comment: This must work. {{ title_prefix }} {{ title }} {{ title_suffix }} Are you sure you added a title to the view?

Comment: Yup, title is added to the view. I even removed my custom template, so the core theme template is used, and that doesn't show the title either.

Comment: You should be able to add in a `{{ dump() }}` debug statement in your twig file, and at least get an idea of what variable are there for you to use. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates for full details on setting up twig debugging.

Comment: and did you flush all caches ?

Comment: Yup! Always do when working with templates :)

Comment: did you try to put the title variable {{ title }} before the article tag

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the twig variable is in the template?

Comment: yes it shouldn't, but i see that you have a duplicated header tag

Comment: A `<header>` tag should not stop the title from being displayed. I have also checked the page source, there is no 'hidden' header...

Answer (score 11):

You have to use `{{ view.title }}`.

Comment: I can confirm this solution works for me. `{{ title }}` delivers empty content, while `{{ view.title }}` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The title is only available in the admin preview, see the documentation of the template:

*views-view.html.twig*

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for main view template.
 *
 * Available variables:
 ...
 * - title: Title of the view, only used when displaying in the admin preview.
```

In other cases add it in preprocess:

*mytheme.theme*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for views templates.
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  $variables['title'] = [
    '#markup' => $view->getTitle(),
  ];
}
```

Comment: Eurgh, what nonsense! what is the point of only showing the title in the preview? Will using the preprocess hook work with a multilingual setup?

Comment: This is because the title is displayed in a title block. I don't see why this shouldn't work in multilingual.

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround is to add a "Global: Text area" field in the view header and use :

```
<h1>[view:title]</h1>
```

This will do the trick in most cases if you don't use the header for something else.

Comment: There's a bug with this though -- it decodes encoded characters like "&" :(